# Installing Vintageous Package

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to install the Vintageous package so that I can use Vim commands in Sublime. I downloaded the Vintageous.sublime-package file and added it to the Installed Packages folder, as I was told to do here: https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous#vintageous.

Then I restarted Sublime, reopened it, and pressed Esc to enter command mode. Nothing happened -- Sublime is still behaving like it was before.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my "Preferences.sublime-settings --User" file:

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
"create_window_at_startup": true,
"draw_white_space": "all",
"find_selected_text": true,
"font_size": 19,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "ANSIescape",
    "BeautifyRuby",
    "Cucumber",
    "Javascript Beautify",
    "OmniMarkupPreviewer",
    "PackageResourceViewer",
    "Pretty JSON",
    "ProductiveSnippetsRuby",
    "SublimeCodeIntel",
    "Sublimerge Pro",
    "Vintage",
    "WordHighlight"
],
"move_to_limit_on_up_down": false,
"open_files_in_new_window": false,
"scroll_past_end": true,
"show_full_path": true,
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [Sublime Package Manager](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) instead.

It's extremely easy.

1. Copy and paste the snippet you find in the installation page, and then you paste it in the Sublime console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>)
2. After that, you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, type in `Install Package`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then type `Vintageous`
3. The package should appear in the list
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. After you restart Sublime, it should be working

Comment: I did exactly these 5 things and pressed Esc to enter command mode, but it's still behaving as it was before.

Comment: Could you share you user settings? `Ctrl+Shift+P`, type `Settings - User`, and then your user settings should show up. Could you share that file?

Comment: Sure -- I included the file in the question.

Comment: Man, you shouldn't have any problem with it. As a last resort, have you considering reinstalling sublime text? Try to do that, and check if Vintageous works after you do it.

Comment: For step #2 above, nothing happens when I type `Install Package` + <Enter>. I'm on build 4152 (latest as I type).